Driving large LCD with stm32
"I am working on a project that requires the use of a TFT LCD. In the current version, I am using an SSD1963 LCD driver with an STM32F405 (-VGT6) microcontroller and the FSMC peripheral. I have successfully driven 5-inch (800x480) and 7-inch (800x480) LCDs, and everything works well.
However, for potential future developments that might require driving larger LCDs with higher resolutions, I am considering alternative methods for driving the LCD. Should I continue using a separate LCD driver with the STM32, or should I utilize the built-in driver of the STM32 microcontroller?
Does anyone have experience with this or can offer some guidance?
Thank you in advance.

Physical size is fairly irrelevant in terms of "LCD Control", though it may be an important consideration when it comes to power - especially for things like the backlight.
The resolution and refresh rate are the key factors, which in turn influence the pixel clock speed... if you're using a serial interface then color depth is also important.
800x480 is already way beyond the RAM available in an STM32F405, even for RGB565 (i.e: 16-bit color) - you're looking at a 750kB frame buffer, while the STM32F405 has a total of 192kB for everything (which is actually made up of smaller chunks of different memories - 112kB, 16kB and 64kB).

Should I continue using a separate LCD driver with the STM32, or should I utilize the built-in driver of the STM32 microcontroller?

This is entirely up to you and the application, available space, budget, performance requirements, etc... bear in mind that if you are looking towards higher resolutions, then you'll likely want to upgrade from the STM32F4 family or lean more heavily on an LCD controller like you're already doing. You may also be forced into using faster serial interfaces like LVDS or MIPI, depending on the panel you select.
Even the SSD1963 you're using at the moment only has a 1215kB frame buffer, which isn't many more pixels than you're already using - you could reach VGA (800x600, 16-bit color) if it's supported by the device, but that's about it!
